# SocketRocket delegate methods not getting called when in Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I moved SocketRocket into a custom framework and now the delegate methods are not getting called. This code does work when it isn't in a framework, it is running on the main thread and the delegate isn't nill.

```
   _mSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"wss://websocket.url.here"]]];
            _mSocket.delegate = self;
            attempts = 0;
            [_mSocket open];

- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket;
{
    NSLog(@"Websocket Connected");

    // Configure SSL/TLS settings
    NSMutableDictionary *settings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];



    [settings setObject:@"wss://websocket.test.clearcaptions.com" forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];



    //  // Allow self-signed certificates
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                 forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];

    //  // In fact, don't even validate the certificate chain
    [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
                 forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain];




    }

    - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
    {
        NSLog(@":( Websocket Failed With Error %@", error);
        _mSocket = nil;
        [self _reconnect];
    }

    - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message;
    {
        NSLog(@"Received \"%@\"", message);
    }

    - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didCloseWithCode:(NSInteger)code reason:(NSString *)reason wasClean:(BOOL)wasClean;
    {
        NSLog(@"WebSocket closed");
        [mDelegate protocolMessageAvailable:@"" msgType:STATE_NETWORK_OFFLINE];
        _mSocket = nil;
    }

    - (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceivePong:(NSData *)pongPayload;
    {
        NSLog(@"Websocket received pong");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. I created the framework in the viewdidload and it drops its value when the method is complete.

Comment: I think this is my problem...can you elaborate on the solution?

Comment: Actually my issue was that the delegate class was going out of scope as I had just declared it in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method as a local variable

Comment: same idea as my problem.